# Iterating over start and end dates for multiple API calls

Tags: python, api

I am working on an API call to find some data. The API call is a simple get command, with all the query parameters as part of the URL itself.

These query parameters include the information I need plus the dates for which I need the data these dates are start and end dates in this form: "YYYY-MM-ddThh:mm:ssT". The API is limited to only return a month's data in each call, so I would want to run the query multiple times to fetch for example  a years data and pince them all together in a data frame.But I have no idea how to do the iteration.

Comment: You will need [`datetime.datetime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime), [`datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) and [`datetime.timedelta()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta). Initialize some initial `datetime` then iterate over some range and add/subtract `timedelta` object initialized using current value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.